# Get Cookies from request header Python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I would like to get cookies information from request header using Python requests. Only the default path value cookies appears in the dictionary:

```
post= requests.post(url)
```

[image]

The yellowed cookies coming from a different path, and they are not in the RequestCookiJar.
Is there a way to get them?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cookies` attribute of the `response`.

For example:

```
requests.get('https://youtube.com').cookies
```

Or

```
response = requests.get('https://youtube.com')
response.cookies
```

Which outputs:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='GPS', value='1', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.youtube.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, expires=1689592862, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE', value='QRMWYOTx2RI', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.youtube.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, expires=1705143062, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None, 'SameSite': 'none'}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

This cookie will be usable in Python `requests` module, using cookies argument in requests, e.g. `requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)` or `requests.post(url, cookies=cookies)`

Also, if you're trying to get cookies in JSON or dictionary format, yo can use `get_dict` function with cookies.

For example:

```
requests.get('https://youtube.com').cookies.get_dict()
```

outputs

```
{'GPS': '1', 'VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE': 'vqGIU2msd10'}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried: I got exactly the same result. The yellowed ones are missing from the cookies dictionary.

Comment: No worries @Erika, you can try playing around with the request in Postman, sometimes some of the cookies are based on the headers.

Comment: The JSESSIONID is added to each request header automatically, by the page calling the method. I would like to get that info to be able to create request manually, but fist I need to get the JSESSIONID.

Comment: @Erika, you can try `requests.Session().get('Your website').cookies.get_dict()`, and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, It gives me back the response headers cookies, but JSESSIONID is in the request headers cookie. :/

Comment: @Erika, once a cookie comes in response headers, it also goes to the next requests' headers.

Comment: Yes it is true for the rest of the cookies, but JSESSIONID in not in the get_dict() .

Comment: @Erika, then try playing around with Postman for the request, which headers work with your URL, and which ones create the session cookie which you're looking for.